# I want to understand this expression about "language", is it literally used or not?

Tags: meaning

Everyone automatically categorizes and generalizes all the time. Unconsciously. It is not a question of being prejudiced or enlightened. Categories are absolutely necessary for us to function. They give structure to our thoughts. Imagine if we saw every item and every scenario as truly unique ― we would not even have **a language to describe the world around us**. But the necessary and useful instinct to generalize can distort our world view. It can make us mistakenly group together things, or people, or countries that are actually very different. It can make us assume everything or everyone in one category is similar. And, maybe, most unfortunate of all, it can make us jump to conclusions about a whole category based on a few, or even just one, unusual example.

Question) Does the expression "a language"  literally mean "language"? (for example, Korean, English etc,,,)

I think it points to **a kind of** **structure** to see the world more clearly and logically.

What do you guys think about it?

Comment: The use cited does not imply a specific language.  It is suggesting the language that Grok used when speaking with Ork, and every language since then.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the expression "a language" literally mean "language"? (for example, Korean, English etc?)

Yes. You need to look at the differences between countable and uncountable nouns.

**A** language = an/one example of a language (e.g. French is a language)

**Language** = an abstract idea or concept of all those things that can be described as "language."